# Find the values of x that give the system infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been given the following system and asked to find which values of x give the system an infinite number of solutions:

$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\-2 & x & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 3 & -1 & 0 & 0\\5 & -2 & 7 & 1-x & 0\\2 & 5 & -1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\end{bmatrix}$=
$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

I believe the solution should be found by putting the matrix in reduced row form then observing which values of x remove an equation. However I have run into some trouble putting this into reduced form where the variable x is in the second column.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force it, you might as well.

From multiplying the first row with the column vector and comparing, you get $3a=0$, so that $a=0$.

From the second line, you get $-2a+bx=0$, which gives $bx=0$, which gives $b=0$ unless $x=0$, in which case $b$ could have any value, leading to infinitely many solutions. For now, assume  that $x \neq 0$, so that $b=0$.

Then, from the third line, $a+3b-c=0$, giving $c=0$.

From the fourth line, you get $d(1-x) = 0$, which gives any $d=0$ unless $x=1$, which gives infinitely many solutions for $d$. Hence, we'll assume $x \neq 1$ so that $d=0$.

From the fifth line, we get $e=0$.

Hence, given that $x \neq 0,1$, there is only one solution, that is that all are zero.

Now, if $x=0$, then notice that there are infinitely many solutions, same for $x=1$. Hence, these are the value of $x$ giving infinitely many solutions.

If you know what the determinant is, then this question is much easier to do. If you want to know the trick, I can tell you: The point is, the determinant of the big matrix is $-3(x)(1-x)$, and it is known that the number of solutions is infinite exactly when this is zero. $-3(x)(1-x)=0$ only when $x=0,1$, so the answer comes directly.

Comment: The determinant trick is definitely what we were supposed to use. That makes things much easier.

Comment: Oh, I see. But the brute forcing just made the issue clearer, I hope. Great, then.